# Getting “DVD: Copy-protection fail” error when trying to play DVD in Media Player Classic

Tags: dvd, drm, copy-protection, media-player-classic

I'm trying to play a DVD in [Media Player Classic](http://mpc-hc.sourceforge.net/), when I get the error

```
DVD: Copy-protection fail.
```

What can I do to play [my DVD](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0830515/)? Preferably in Media Player Classic.

I'm running Windows 7. It works in Windows Media Player, but as it doesn't give me as many configuration options as MPC, I'd prefer to use MPC.

And of course this is a genuine DVD, as this only affects us poor suckers that actually buy DVDs.

Comment: Does it work in other players? Is it a pirated dvd? You didn't even tell us what OS you are using, some details might help.

Comment: Sorry, updated the question.

Comment: Great update! thanks, I wish I could help you but it has been so long since I last used MPC.

Comment: Feel free to recommend another software where this works, that is otherwise comparable to MPC :-)

Comment: Seems a valid question to me, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tonight it magically just worked. Don't know what I did different. Maybe it was because I started the video when the movie window was on the projector screen, instead of moving it there afterwards. Maybe because I skipped right to the movie.

Answer (score 4):

The [Media Player Classic FAQ](http://www.codecguide.com/faq_mpc.htm) says :

> **Q:**    I get a "DVD: Macrovision Failed"
>   error when trying to play a DVD  
>   **A:**    This may happen if you have are
>   using Haali video renderer. 
> Solution
>   is to change the video renderer in MPC
>   options.
>
> ```
> MPC options -> Playback -> Output
> ```

Apart from this, you may try updating the video driver from the manufacturer's website, or abandon MPC.

Comment: Tonight it magically just worked. Don't know what I did different. Maybe it was because I started the video when the movie window was on the projector screen, instead of moving it there afterwards. Maybe because I skipped right to the movie. Feel kinda stupid, voting to delete question. Thank you anyway!

Comment: I would rather have added the solution as an answer, as this can be useful for others. Leave me a note if want me to vote for reopen.

Comment: Yeah sure, that makes sense. Please open again ;)

Answer (score 3):

Since you are fine with a recommendation I personally use [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) media player as my de-facto program for playing and streaming any media. I haven't run into much it can't play, in fact I have never run into anything Windows Media Player can play that VLC can't. It is also one of our featured programs if you check out the community promotions on the [right](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/2164/community-promotion-ads-1h-2011/2167#2167).

Comment: Tonight it magically just worked. Don't know what I did different. Maybe it was because I started the video when the movie window was on the projector screen, instead of moving it there afterwards. Maybe because I skipped right to the movie. Feel kinda stupid, voting to delete question. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem!

I simply went into Media Player Classic > Options > Playback > Direct Show video, click the drop down menu and check Advanced Video Renderer and it plays DVDs.

Answer (score -1):

I just had that error, but it was because I bought my USB player in Japan, and it was set for dvd region 2. Blue-ray is the same region for US and Japan, so I never noticed the problem before.

Anyway, I changed the region to 1 in device manager, and DVDs play fine.